# How to animate a text to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6avyo8zf/

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".content-box").hover(function () {
        $(this).children("div:first-child").find(".hdrText").animate({ 'marginLeft': '+=100%' }, 2000);
    }, function () {
        $(this).children("div:first-child").find(".hdrText").animate({ 'marginLeft': '-=100%' }, 2000);
    });
});
```

How can I modify the script so that on hover, the text animates to the right until it comes to the right black border and off hover, the text returns to the original position.

Comment: You don't really need javascript for this

Comment: I am using IE9 and that's the target unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contents are not too dynamic, as in the image is a fixed size, you can use something like:

```
$(function () {
    var hdr =$(".content-box").hover(function () {      
    hdr.stop().animate( {left: $(this).parent().width() - hdr.width() - startoffset } , 2000);
    }, function () {
    hdr.stop().animate({left:0}, 2000);
    }).find("div:first-child>.hdrText").css('position', 'relative');
  var startoffset = hdr.offset().left;
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6avyo8zf/6/)

position relative is required for the `left` animation, and is set here with jquery, but can be set in css as well.
The .stop() is an extra addition to make sure the previous animation is discontinued. e.g. the animation to left is still being executed when the hover is ended.

Comment: Thank you. I just tested the Fiddle and might be what I need. I will test in my project and update.

Comment: Just one question, if I have multiple of the same class, how can I ensure it only targets the one that I have hovered over?

Comment: One way would be to attach the hover events separately: https://jsfiddle.net/6avyo8zf/8/ , would that suffice for the target scenario?

Comment: I tried the same thing but my text on the second box is scroll to the right way off the target. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS only, no need for that jQuery code. It basically works by making `.hdrText` change when `.content-box` is hovered.

Demo:

```css
.content-box {
  position: relative; /* required for absolute positioning in children to work */
}

.hdrText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 44px;
  right: 100%; /* allows us to animate the right offset */
  text-align: right; /* makes sure text does not overflow */
  transition: 2s;
}

.content-box:hover .hdrText {
  right: 10px; /* animate right offset to 10px (gap from edge)
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 40%; overflow: hidden; float: left; border: 1px solid black;">
  <div class="content-box-blue content-box">
    <div class="title content-box-title">
      <div style="display: inline-block; width: 30px; height: 30px; vertical-align: middle; overflow: hidden; padding: 0 10px 0 0;">
        <img src="theimage.png" style="z-index: 5; display: inline-block; width: 30px; height: 30px; vertical-align: middle;" class="" alt="sd">
      </div>
      <span class="hdrText">Announcements</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle fork: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/7080u1a1/2/

---

## Edit - jQuery Solution

I just realized that you need IE9 support. So basically instead of the `transition` animation, use jQuery `animate` function to move the text. You'll have to keep the CSS rules I added tho.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".content-box").hover(function() {
    $(this).children("div:first-child").find(".hdrText").animate({
      'right': '10px'
    }, 2000);
  }, function() {
    $(this).children("div:first-child").find(".hdrText").animate({
      'right': '100%'
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.content-box {
  position: relative; /* required for absolute positioning in children to work */
}

.hdrText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 44px;
  right: 100%; /* allows us to animate the right offset */
  text-align: right; /* makes sure text does not overflow */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 40%; overflow: hidden; float: left; border: 1px solid black;">
  <div class="content-box-blue content-box">
    <div class="title content-box-title">
      <div style="display: inline-block; width: 30px; height: 30px; vertical-align: middle; overflow: hidden; padding: 0 10px 0 0;">
        <img src="theimage.png" style="z-index: 5; display: inline-block; width: 30px; height: 30px; vertical-align: middle;" class="" alt="sd">
      </div>
      <span class="hdrText">Announcements</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/7fgno2cL/1/)

I would recommend the `hoverIntent` jQuery plugin to avoid firing the function so many times while the animation is still running..

Comment: I would like the Jquery version as it will work with IE9. jsfiddle.net/6avyo8zf/1 but it just keeps going and doesn't come back to the original position on mouseout.

Comment: @SiKni8 updated with a jQuery solution, let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want pure jQuery support you can do this, you just need to calculate the exact proportions to add and subtract taking into account all the other elements.

```
$(function() {
    // Load all needed elements
    var content = $(".content-box");
    var contentTitle = $(".content-box-title");
    var text = content.children("div:first-child").find(".hdrText");
    var theimage = $('#theimage');
    var currentAnimate = null;
    content.hover(function() {
        // Get titles total width
        var contentWidth = contentTitle.width();
        // Get the texts total width
        var textWidth = text.width();
        // Get the images total width
        var theimageWidth = theimage.width();
        // Get the padding on the image
        var imageParentPadding = theimage.parent().css('padding-right');
        // Add text, image and padding + 5 to accommodate changing screen size together so we can subtract that from content width
        var subtractWidth = textWidth + theimageWidth + parseInt(imageParentPadding) + 5;
        // Save value to move back to same position in case screen size changes between animations
        currentAnimate = contentWidth - subtractWidth;
        // Animate margin left by the total content width minus the width of all the other elements and paddings
        text.animate({
            'marginLeft': '+=' + currentAnimate
        }, 2000);
    }, function () {
        text.animate({
            'marginLeft': '-=' + currentAnimate
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6avyo8zf/7/

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to add a margin right to offset the margin being added to the left side.  This will give the impression of the text moving without resizing itself or moving about the page.  You'll want this negative of the equal amount:

```
{'marginLeft': '+=100%', 'marginRight': '-=100%'}
```

I also noticed, the animation gets jumpy when rapidly hovered over.  You can look into the mouseenter and mouseleave for those as well as adding a stop() before your animate to cancel the previous animation:

https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6avyo8zf/1/ but it just keeps going and doesn't come back to the original position on mouseout.